# How can I write a query to show 0 instead of no result in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query in Access 2013 that shows nothing when there is no data in the resulting dynaset. I want it to show 0.

My report is generated for each month so I format the `invClosureDate` for year and month. When there is no data, the query returns nothing, the report requirement is to show 0 when there is no data.

```
SELECT Format([invClosureDate],"yyyy") AS invCY, Format([invClosureDate],"mmm") AS invCM, Sum(Abs(IIf([invStatus]="closed",1,0))) AS Inc, tblInvestigations.invClosureDate
FROM tblInvestigations
GROUP BY Format([invClosureDate],"yyyy"), Format([invClosureDate],"mmm"), tblInvestigations.invClosureDate
HAVING (((tblInvestigations.invClosureDate)=[Forms]![tblInvestigations]![txtInvDate]));
```

Comment: Review https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3844021/Reporting-whats-not-there.htm. Listings 8, 9, 10 are examples of what I usually advise if you want records. Alternatively, have the report display a label or textbox with "No data available" when there are no records.

Comment: The answer was in the comment to the article you mentioned. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is, as already mentioned is to use a union query with zero/default values.

Another option would be build a zero/default value query and use VBA to change the change the record source of the report to this query if there are no records in the data query. This would need to be done before opening the report.

Comment: My vba :    newSQL = "SELECT Format([invClosureDate], ""yyyy"") As incDY, Format([invClosureDate], ""mmm"") As incDM, Sum(Abs(IIf([invStatus] = ""closed"", 1, 0))) As invClosed" _
            & " FROM [tblInvestigations]" _
            & " WHERE invClosureDate = Forms!tblInvestigations!txtInvDate" where is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved with
SELECT Count(tblInvestigations.invStatus) AS CountOfinvStatus
FROM tblInvestigations
WHERE (((tblInvestigations.invStatus)="closed") AND ((Format([invClosureDate],"mmmm"))=[Forms]![tblInvestigations]![txtInvDate]));